# Selenium IDE - Scroll in div?

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

```
<div id="aaa"> [lots of text] SHOW ME</div>

#aaa {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3NXtJ/

is possible make scrool to DOWN and show me text "SHOW ME" ?
i cant record this in SELENIUM IDE, but maybe this is possible?

Comment: try this http://seleniumexamples.com/blog/tag/scrolling/

Comment: thanks, but this is not for php, i dont understand this

Answer (score 2):

use runScript to run the following snippet

```
document.getElementById('aaa').scrollTop = document.getElementById('aaa').scrollHeight;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variant on the answer provided by @chim (thanks, it put me on this track and solved my particular need!), here I needed to find a DIV element by its path - used querySelector - and scroll it horizontally:

```
var select=document.querySelector("div#MyOuterDivId div.datagrid-view2 div.datagrid-body");select.scrollLeft=100;
```